# Form not getting populated for editing in Hibernate+Spring MVC

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am working on a spring mvc+hibernate CRUD application.

My create and Add functionalities are working properly, but when I use the

edit functionality from the home page, the form is not getting populated for editing.

The id is auto-generated.

My Code :

////////////////////////////////Controller//////////////////////////////

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @Autowired 
    private PersonService ps;



    @RequestMapping("/")
            public ModelAndView listPersons(ModelAndView model) throws IOException {
            List<Person> listper = ps.list();
            model.addObject("personsList", listper);
            model.setViewName("index");
            return model; 

    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/newPerson", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView newPerson(ModelAndView model) throws IOException {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Person p = new Person();
        model.addObject("person", new Person());
        model.setViewName("AddPerson");

        return new ModelAndView("AddPerson", "person", new Person());



    }

    @RequestMapping("/save")
    public String save(@ModelAttribute Person p) {
        Person person=ps.getPersonById(p.getId());
        person=p;
        //ps.getPersonById(p.getId());
        ps.save(person);

        return "index";

    }
/*  @RequestMapping(value = "/savePerson")
    public ModelAndView savePerson(ModelAndView model,@ModelAttribute Person p) {

        Person p1  = new Person();
        ps.updatePerson(p1);
        //List<Person> listp = ps.list();
        //model.addObject("personslist",listp);
        model.setViewName("AddPerson");
        return new ModelAndView("AddPerson", "person", new Person());



    }   */  

     @RequestMapping("/editPerson/{id}")
        public ModelAndView editPerson(@RequestParam Integer id){
         Person person=ps.getPersonById(id);
         ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView();
         mv.addObject("p", person);
         mv.setViewName("AddPerson");
            return mv;
        }

     @RequestMapping("/remove/{id}")
        public String removePerson(@PathVariable("id") int id){

            this.ps.removePerson(id);
            return "redirect:/persons";
        }



}
```

////////////////////////////DAOImpl///////////////////////

```
@Transactional 
@Repository
public class PersonDAOImpl implements PersonDAO,java.io.Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonDAOImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf){
        this.sessionFactory = sf;
    }



    public void save(Person p) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session s = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
        s.saveOrUpdate(p);
        tx.commit();
        s.close();

        System.out.println("Record successfully inserted");

    }


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public List<Person> list() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Person> personsList = session.createQuery("from Person").list();
        for(Person p : personsList){
            logger.info("Person List::"+p);
        }
        return personsList;

    }






    public void updatePerson(Person p) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("Person id="+p.getId());
         // Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();


            /* Person person = session.get(Person.class, p.getId());
             person.setName(p.getName()); // modify the loaded object somehow
             session.update(person);*/
        Session  session = new Configuration().configure()
                    .buildSessionFactory().openSession();

            Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
        p = new Person();
        p.setId(p.getId());
        p.setName(p.getName());
        p.setGender(p.getGender());
        p.setAddress(p.getAddress());
        p.setSalary(p.getSalary());
    session.saveOrUpdate(p);


    }



    public Person getPersonById(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();      
        Person p = (Person) session.load(Person.class, new Integer(id));
        logger.info("Person loaded successfully, Person details="+p);
        return p;
    }



    public void removePerson(Person p) {
        /*// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        //Person p = (Person) session.load(Person.class, new Integer(p.getId()));
        Person p1 = getPersonById(p.getId());

            session.delete(p.getId());

        logger.info("Person deleted successfully, person details=");*/
        Session  session = new Configuration().configure()
                .buildSessionFactory().openSession();

        Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
        p = new Person();
        p=getPersonById(p.getId());
        session.delete(p);

    }
```

/////////////////////////////////////index.jsp///////////////////////////

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
 <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>


<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Welcome</title>
    </head> 
    <body>
    <h2>Hello World!</h2>

<h3><a href="/MainAssignment3/newPerson">Add Person</a></h3>
    <table border="1">
<tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>address</th>
    <th>gender</th>
    <th>salary</th>

</tr>   
 <c:forEach var="person" items='${personsList}' varStatus="status">
    <tr>
        <td>${status.index+1}</td>
        <td>${person.id}</td>
        <td>${person.address}</td>
        <td>${person.gender}</td>
        <td>${person.salary}</td>
        <td>${person.name}</td>
        <td>
        <a href="/MainAssignment3/editPerson/{id}?id=${person.id}">Edit</a>
            <a href="/MainAssignment3/remove/{id}?id=${person.id}">Delete</a>
        </td>

    </tr>

</c:forEach> 


</table>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I also tried using HQL and criteria, but those will work only after my form gets populated from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update your daoimpl method as below!

```
public void removePerson(Integer id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Person p = (Person) session.load(Person.class, new Integer(id));
        session.delete(p);
        logger.info("Person deleted successfully, person details=");

    }
```

And controller as given below.

```
@RequestMapping("/removePerson")
    public String remove(HttpServletRequest req) {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("id"));
        ps.removePerson(id);
        return "redirect:http://localhost:8080/MainAssignment3/";

    }
```